# Add multiple UITextView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am trying to display an article in a ViewController.

The output that I receive from the API divides the article into paragraphs, and each paragraph is a node in the JSON. For example,

```
{
 "para" : 1,
 "content" : "some long paragraph"
},
{
 "para" : 1,
 "content" : "some long paragraph"
}
```

I want to display this content as one long article, but I want to let each paragraph to be viewed in one textView instead of combining all the paragraphs and view in one textView.

I am on Xcode 8, Swift 3. I use Cocoapods, so libraries are welcome.

Comment: Better to put it in tableview rather than programatically creating all textviews.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Text view , then you don't need to create multiple textview. Just use a single textview.

Use a for loop on your response object and append all the paragraph's content in a single string using /n after each paragraph. And then simply set that string value into textview. That's it. I hope it will work for you better..